# CNF-SAT is NP-complete if and only if CNF-UNSAT is co-NP-complete?

Tags: computational-complexity, np-complete, satisfiability, conjunctive-normal-form

I have shown that a language $A$ is NP-complete $\iff$ its complement $\overline{A}$ is co-NP-complete.

Also, I have shown that CNF-SAT is NP-complete.

Since UNSAT is the complement of SAT, then CNF-UNSAT is the complement of CNF-SAT and CNF-UNSAT is co-NP-complete, right?

Comment: Right. ${{{}}}$